Include known in top folder is unknown in subdirectory
i got the problem, that a library known in main.c is unknown in the subdirs
This is my file structure:
src
|--ui/
|    |--Screens/
|    |      |--blah.c
|    |
|    |--CMakeLists.txt
|    |--ui.c
|    |--ui.h
|
|--CMakeLists.txt
|--main.c

My top level CMakeLists.txt looks like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)

find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})

project(SomeProject)

target_include_directories(app PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ui
    )

# List all subdirectories to be added to the project
set(subdirs
    ui
)

foreach(subdir ${subdirs})
    add_subdirectory(${subdir})
endforeach()

target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE ${subdirs})

set(app_SRCS
    main.c
    ui/ui.c
)

# Local sources of app
target_sources(app PRIVATE ${app_SRCS})

The CMakeLists.txt in the ui folder:
set(UI_SOURCES
    "ui.c"
)

add_library(ui ${UI_SOURCES})

So main.c knows the include for lvgl but ui.c doesn't.
I guess it's more like a cmake related problem. I hope you are able help me.
I tried different combinations on my CMakeLists files but they didn't do the trick.

You use target_include_directories(app PRIVATE ...), so the include directory is added only for the target app. This directory is not added to other targets, including ones created in the subdirectories.

Is main.c supposed to be built into an executable? Because at the moment I am also missing an add_executable, add_library or add_custom_target in the main CMakeLists.txt.
